# How can I find out whereby a Linux module refers to another?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

On a Linux 2.4.25 system I have two loadable kernel modules, `com20020` and `xsoe`. These modules should be independent of each other, but `/proc/modules` has the lines

```
xsoe                    4528   0 (unused)
com20020               10112   0 [xsoe]
```

- saying that `xsoe` is referring to `com20020`. Perhaps there is a programming error so that `xsoe` inadvertently uses a symbol from `com20020`. How can I find the cause of this dependency (preferably without unloading `com20020`)? (`depmod -n` offers no clue.)

Comment: Linux kernel 2.4.25 is so old... Even format of `/proc/modules` output is different now. As for symbol usage, the simplest way to check, whether `xsoe` uses symbols from `com20020` is to examine its `Module.symvers` file (in the same build directory where `xsoe` is build).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but there is no `Module.symvers` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at `/proc/ksyms` for suspicious symbols in `com20020` which might also appear in the source of `xsoe`; eventually I saw the line

```
d129e694 debug        [com20020]
```

there. Both the sources of `com20020` and `xsoe` had the definitions `unsigned debug;` `MODULE_PARM(debug, "i");` and in the outputs of `nm com20020.o` and `nm xsoe.o` the symbol appeared as *common*:

```
00000004 C debug
```

The cure was to define the object `debug` to have internal linkage (storage-class
`static`).

The search for common symbols could be automated with a `bash` command like

```
join -j 3 <(nm com20020.o) <(nm xsoe.o)|grep C$
```